# Python Flask output dropdown values to page

Tags: python, flask

I have a two dictionaries with several keys and one value for each key. One dict has weekly cumulative work hours, the other weekly cumulative overtime hours. The key is a datetime object, which is calculated to be the beginning of a week. On my webpage I have a dropdown box, which contains the week beginnings

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" name="cumuls" id="select1" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
        <option value="0">Cumulative for week beginning...</option>
        {% for i,j in zip(wks, wks2) %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ j }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </form>
```

(`wks2` is just a nicely formatted version of `wks`, and `wks` is just a list of the keys from the dicts which are datetime objects (the dictionaries have the same keys))

I want to be able to click on an option from the dropdown box and for the corresponding values from the two dictionaries to appear below the dropdown box.

I handle the form here (within an `index()` function), after the if is the end of the index function:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'cumuls' in request.form:
        week_Begin = request.form['cumuls']
        listHours = listDates(current_user.get_id())
        dct_hours, dct_overtime, wks = weeklySum2(listHours)

        #strfdelta is a custom function that formats timedeltas
        cumul_hrs = strfdelta(dct_hours[datetime.fromisoformat(week_Begin)], '%H:%M')

        cumul_overtime = strfdelta(dct_overtime[datetime.fromisoformat(week_Begin)], '%H:%M')

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

listHours = listDates(current_user.get_id())

dct_hours, dct_overtime, wks = weeklySum2(listHours)
print(wks)
# wkbgn = weekbeginning, this just formats the dates nicely
wks2 = [wkbgn.strftime('%A') + ' ' + wkbgn.strftime('%-d') + ' ' + wkbgn.strftime('%b') + ' ' + wkbgn.strftime('%Y') for wkbgn in wks]

currentDay = datetime.today()
start_week = (currentDay - timedelta(days=currentDay.weekday()))

return render_template('index.html', form=form, hoursDb = listHours, dct_overtime=dct_overtime,dct_hours=dct_hours, wks=wks, wks2=wks2, zip=zip)
```

So within the `if 'cumuls'...`, I basically get the cumulative working and overtime hours for the selected week, in `cumul_hrs` and `cumul_overtime`, which works. I essentially want these variables to be displayed on the webpage (below the dropdown box), and the default variable that is displayed will be the current weeks cumulative so far. How could I do this?

Any pointers/tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing the redirect within the elif statement to

```
return redirect(url_for('index', cumul_hrs=cumul_hrs, cumul_overtime=cumul_overtime))
```

and then getting the variables from the URL with:

```
cumul_hrs, cumul_overtime = request.args.get('cumul_hrs'), request.args.get('cumul_overtime')
```

and passing them through `render_template`.